# Python HTTP Error 429 with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-code-429

I am using the following code to resolve redirects to return a links final url

```
def resolve_redirects(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).geturl()
```

Unfortunately I sometimes get `HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests`. What is a good way to combat this? Is the following good or is there a better way.

```
def resolve_redirects(url):
    try:
        return urllib2.urlopen(url).geturl()
    except HTTPError:
        time.sleep(5)
        return urllib2.urlopen(url).geturl()
```

Also, what would happen if there is an exception in the except block?

Comment: I think that's going to depend on the URL that's returning 429 and rate limiting your calls. What's their limit/time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to make sure the HTTP code is actually 429 before re-trying.

That can be done like this:

```
def resolve_redirects(url):
    try:
        return urllib2.urlopen(url).geturl()
    except HTTPError, e:
        if e.code == 429:
             time.sleep(5);
             return resolve_redirects(url)
        raise
```

This will also allow arbitrary numbers of retries (which may or may not be desired).

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#httperror

Comment: How would I specify the # of retries

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned ("arbitrary number of retries"). -- a further improvement would be for it to take a param limiting the number of retries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fine way to handle the exception, though you should check to make sure you are always sleeping for the appropriate amount of time between requests for the given website (for example twitter limits the amount of requests per minute and has this amount clearly shown in their api documentation). So just make sure you're always sleeping long enough.

To recover from an exception within an exception, you can simply embed another try/catch block:

```
def resolve_redirects(url):
    try:
        return urllib2.urlopen(url).geturl()
    except HTTPError:
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            return urllib2.urlopen(url).geturl()
        except HTTPError:
            return "Failed twice :S"
```

Edit: as @jesse-w-at-z points out, you should be returning an URL in the second error case, the code I posted is just a reference example of how to write a nested try/catch.

Comment: Returning a non-URL in the error case is asking for trouble.

Comment: I just posted it in as a code example of a nested catch, I'll make an edit

Answer (score 0):

Adding User-Agent to request header solved my issue:

```
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.example.com/abc.json'
req = request.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'abc-bot')
response = request.urlopen(req)
```